# Windows 10-Is "Reset this PC" option, removes other partitions's content?

Tags: windows-10

Does "Reset this PC" option in troubleshoot(as presented in images below this text) harm or remove other partitions content?

I had the above question and I couldn't find the answer to the question.
But after using "Reset this PC" option, now i know the answer and i thought 
it would be nice to share the answer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: The answer is no, "Reset your PC" is not going to remove content of any partitions other than the partition that contains windows.

The detailed answer is: after clicking "Rest your PC", you will be presented with two options as represented in the below picture
[image]

choosing "Keep my files", not only doesn't remove other partitions's content but it also keeps your personal files which exist in windows's partition.

choosing "Remove everything", to be honest i didn't try this option, but i assume that it just removes content of windows's partition and will leave other partitions untouched.